# How to map integration and multiplication to a serie?

Tags: function-construction, series-expansion, core-language

*For further study of series, they can be put into a different form.

```
Normal[Series[1/(1 - x), {x, 0, 10}]]
```

This serie 1/(1-x) = 1 + x + ... ,must be first integrated and then multiplied by -1 for both sides of the equation.

I was thinking on the `Map` function, but how to do that ?

Comment: `Map` is the right function to use. Which part are you having difficulty?

Comment: Its mapping about a equation, but i think i have to split the mapping for the LHS and RHS of the equation `Normal[Series[1/(1 - x), {x, 0, 10}]`

Comment: You don't need any splitting. Please read the document of `Map` carefully, especially the **Generalizations & Extensions** section. If you still don't get it, execute `f/@(aaa==bbb)` and observe.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that and see what happens

Comment: I do want to integrate first , so i need a integrate operator for f

Comment: @janhardo  Could you explain why you haven't accepted any answers to your questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
eqn = 1/(1 - x) == Normal@Series[1/(1 - x), {x, 0, 10}]
func = expr |-> -Integrate[expr, x];
func /@ eqn
```

Alternatively:

```
Map[func][eqn]
```

To be more compact:

```
-Integrate[#, x] & /@ (1/(1 - x) == Normal@Series[1/(1 - x), {x, 0, 10}])
```

Comment: Never could make it to this...,  This expression `-Integrate[#1, x] &` as pure function is standing for  a indefinite integral operator ?
Next step to do is multiplying by  -1  with Map

Comment: Wait.. this minus sign in `-Integrate[#1, x]`  is -1 multiplying to Integrate , so the equation is now intergated and multiplied.
Yes, the post is crossing..

Comment: @janhardo Yes, if you want to first integrate and then multiply by -1, just define another pure function in a similar manner as I've done above.

Comment: @janhardo If my answer resolves your problem, you can vote it up by [clicking the gray triangle](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), and/or accept it by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/).

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not yet strong in coming up with pure functions.
Need to get more familiar with it.

Comment: @janhardo Have you read e.g. https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/26-pure-anonymous-functions.html or http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node50.html or https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/WorkWithPureFunctions.html  ?

Comment: That's a good study source you give here to me.  I read about pure functions on other places, but that helps me not to understand it yet.

Comment: @janhardo the suggestion that was made that you should be accepting an answer by clicking on the checkmark is good practice in general for the site. This site is meant to be useful for other users that might face similar difficulties and it is easier for them to know which is the preferred approach to a particular question. In the answer by xzczd you can find THREE (3) approach that answer your question. I am just mentioning this as a general comment. It's a (+1) to be honest.

Comment: @kcr , That is certainly a very good answer (1+) which @ xzczd gives to help me in three ways.
Have mentioned this in my own processing of the study material

Answer (score 4):

```
eqn1 = 1/(1 - x) == Series[1/(1 - x), {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

As an alternative to [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) you can use [`ApplySides`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ApplySides.html)

```
eqn2 = ApplySides[-Integrate[#, x] &, eqn1]
```

[image]

```
Series[eqn2[[1]], {x, 0, 11}] == eqn2[[2]]

(* True *)
```

Comment: is useful ,thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Integrate[(-1)*Normal[Series[1/(1 - x), {x, 0, 10}]], x]

(*  -x - x^2/2 - x^3/3 - x^4/4 - x^5/5 - x^6/6 - x^7/7 - x^8/8 - x^9/9 - \
x^10/10 - x^11/11  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: @ Alexei Boulbitch , yes that is the  familiar integrating for the RHS